# C : integer variables randomly change values

Tags: c, char, strcpy

I just started learning the C language. I have a good history with C# and Java though.

```
#include <stdio.h>     
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "info.h"
int main()
{
    int day = 24, month = 3, year = 2016;

    char name[] = "Ahmad\0";
    strcpy(name, "Ahmad(strcpy-ed string)\0"); // <-- LINE 8

    printf("%s made this program on %d-%d-%d\n", name, day, month, year);

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see the values have been assigned to day, month and year. But the problem is the output has competely different values. The output is this

```
Ahmad(strcpy-ed string) made this program on 1920234272-1684352377-1885565556
```

What's more interesting is if i delete line 8 it works properly. Why is this happening?

Comment: When you copy something larger than the container's capacity, shit happens.

Comment: This is an overflow... `Ahmad\0` (6 positions array), and `"Ahmad(strcpy-ed string)\0"` (more than 6, I am lazy to count it) being written over it

Comment: i thought strcpy() would reallocate memory....

Comment: Making sure by reading the documentation is better than "having thought". At least once you encounter a problem it is high time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are copying more bytes into name[] than are allocated for it-- C does not stop you from doing this.  The extra bytes are overwriting other things, in this case your other variables.  You are creating undefined behavior, which is a very bad thing in C programs.

Answer (score 0):

`name` only has place for 8 characters, then you write into other memory, probably your other variables.